# NewRelic PHP-agent Laravel newrelic.transaction_tracer.record_sql = "raw" shows ? instead of value

Tags: php, laravel, newrelic

I have set my NewRelic PHP-agent in our Laravel dev to have newrelic.transaction_tracer.record_sql = "raw", but the values are coming through to the APM as "?" instead of the value.  NewRelic documentation says the value should be coming through https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-configuration/#inivar-tt-sql.

Anyone else encountering this issue?  And if so how did you fix it?

When I set it to "off" the SQL stops coming through as expected.  Setting it to "obfuscated" also has "?" come through instead of the value, as expected.  But then setting it to "raw" again still has "?" come through in the SQL instead of the value.

We have a CodeIgniter PHP setup where the value does come through when set this config to "raw".

newrelic.high_security is not set so defaults to false.

I tried explicitly setting newrelic.framework to "laravel" which did not fix it.

Verified we're on the latest NewRelic agent and PHP minor version:

- PHP version 8.0.30 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2023 08:05:13) ( NTS )
- New Relic PHP-agent version 10.14.0.3-1563e8045968